# Какая функция у буквы Ь?

Tags: мягкий-знак

Скажите, допускается ли такой ответ на вопрос: Какую функцию выполняет буква Ь в конце и середине слова? Буква Ь смягчает предшествующий согласный звук в конце и середине слова.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В двух указанных позициях  Ь может обозначать мягкость согласных (соль, галька), а также грамматическую форму (стричь, стричься).

Если речь идет о мягкости согласных, то правильно ответить так:

**Буква Ь обозначает мягкость согласного звука  на конце слова, а также в середине слова перед другим согласным.**

Пояснение

Буква Ь смягчает звук ― неточное выражение.

Желательно указать, что буква Ь обозначает мягкость согласного в середине слова в определенной позиции, когда за ним следует другой согласный.

Answer (score 2):

[Три роли мягкого знака](https://rosuchebnik.ru/material/rol-myagkogo-znaka/):

- показатель мягкости согласных;
- разделитель (перед буквами е, ё, и, ю) — только в середине слова;
- показатель формы слова (после шипящих).